# Laravel 8 not running newly created tests, and not picking up deleted tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm just getting started with the Laravel 8 testing suite and have opted to create a feature test for my account creation process. I've ran `php artisan make:test AccountCreation` and have written the first test case as a function, however, when I run `php artisan test` it's not picking up my feature tests, why?

Equally, if I try to delete the default example test, I get an error telling me that the test can't be found? What am I missing?

**tests/Feature/AccountCreation.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AccountCreation extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_creates_user_account_successfully()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/account/create');
        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
}
```

Is there a special command I need to run for Laravel to pick up these tests?

[image: no tests]

Comment: Unless otherwise configured, I believe PHPUnit looks only for classes that end with Test, so you can probably just change `AccountCreation` to `AccountCreationTest`. Oh, and rename the file accordingly as well.

Comment: *"Oh, and rename the file accordingly as well"* — "Confirmed. That's what I forgot some time as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing), you should append 'Test' to your test class, because PHPUnit will check all classes end with Test, so change:

```
class AccountCreation extends TestCase { ...
```

to:

```
class AccountCreationTest extends TestCase { ...
```

Don't forget to change your class file name.

Answer (score 4):

/** @test */

Put this before every test. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For others who end up at this question but for whom the accepted answer does not help.  PHPUnit expects the test class to end in 'Test' and **also** for the individual test method to start with the word 'test'.

So this works as per @Abolfazl Mohajeri's answer:

```
class AccountCreationTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_creates_user_account_successfully()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

This does not run tests (the original question from @Ryan H):

```
class AccountCreation extends TestCase
{
    public function test_creates_user_account_successfully()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

This also will not run tests:

```
class AccountCreationTest extends TestCase
{
    public function it_creates_user_account_successfully()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

@keepyourmouthshut's answer works because of the PHPUnit annotation [documented here](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.0/annotations.html#test)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this issue because my data provider wasn't a static function.
By changing it to a static function, my test could run properly.

Answer (score -1):

My issue was that in one place my code was throwing a `QueryException`, which caused the tests to stop executing without any errors in the console.

Since it wasn't clear which test was causing the error, I had to comment tests one by one to find the broken one and use debugger to find the problematic part.